# Where to get ipkg package nfs-utils?

Tags: nfs, synology, ipkg

The `ipkg list` subcommand states that `nfs-utils` is supposed to be preferred over `nfs-server` (I'm using http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/unstable and checked http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/stable, too). Where can I get this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to activate package sources in `/opt/etc/ipkg.conf`.